# Trying to condition my do-while to stop exiting program in terminal. Menu does not loop in while as desired with current statements

Tags: c++, c++11, menu, do-while

I have an issue with my do-while loop where it will exit the program no     matter the input or my statements in while.

I'VE TRIED CHANGING

```
 while(menureturn > '4' || menuselect < '1');"
```

TO

```
 while(menureturn > '4' && menuselect < '1');
```

HERE IS THE SOURCE CODE MY PROJECT

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int choice, menuselect;
char menureturn;

int menu() {
    cout << "1. Math Menu" << endl;
    cout << "2. Currency Conversion" << endl;
    cout << "3. Cryto Currencies" << endl;
    cout << "4. Display Time Zone selection" << endl;
    cout << ":" << endl;
    cin >> menuselect;
    return menuselect;

}

int main()
{

    do {
        menu();
    } while(menureturn > '4' && menuselect < '1');

    return 0;
}
```

MY OUTPUT

```
1. Math Menu
2. Currency Conversion
3. Cryto Currencies
4. Display Time Zone selection
:
6

C:\Users\Gage\source\repos\Menu\Debug\Menu.exe (process 35580) exited      with code 0.
To automatically close the console when debugging stops, enable               Tools->Options->Debugging->Automatically close the console when debugging stops.
```

Press any key to close this window . . .

Comment: Voting to close as a typo. `while(menureturn > '4' && menuselect < '1')` should be `while(menuselect < '4' && menuselect > '1')` (remove `menureturn` and flip the comparison operators).  You can get rid of `menureturn` as it is unused.

Comment: @NathanOliver But `menuselect` is an `int`, hence the correct bounds, for such loop would be [49; 52], which is not obvious, from the users perspective, and probably would be the next question the OP would ask about, when the current loop doesn't perform as expected :)

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Since it's an int, shouldn't the bounds be `4` and `1` (integral literals)?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The problem is `cin >> menuselect;` will give `4`, not `'4'`.  They'll also need to change that.

Comment: Either way it is all a bunch of typos.  Use the right variable and the right types and it'll work.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Exactly. So, one would need to change the loop conditions to e.g. `menuselect < 4`, instead of `menuselect < '4'`.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I guess I'm not able to interpret your comment the way you intended. I read *"hence the correct bounds, for such loop would be [49; 52]"* as saying that they should change the condition to compare with the values 49 and 52 instead.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Apparently I failed to communicate exactly what I had in mind (english.exe has stopped working). What I intended to say with this line, was the description of how the code would behave, if one didn't change the value compared against, in addition to changing the variable, compared against.

Comment: You never assign to `menureturn` yet it is used in your loop condition. This is undefined behavior.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So I changed it to integral literals and I'm still getting the issue. Just exits program despite the statements in while.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was that you were comparing if an `int` number, was the same as `char` when you put `' '` around your numbers.

```
} while(menureturn > '4' && menuselect < '1');
```

And you did not assign `menureturn` to any value which just leaves it being null and doesn't contain a value, and therefore should not be used in a condition.

So this can be fixed very simply by first not comparing in the `Do-While-Loop` using a `char` but rather by using an `int`. Then we can simply just assign the `menu()` function to an `int` - since that is the return type and just compare that value

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

// choice variable
int choice;

// the menu function
int menu()
{
    cout << "1: Do Something" << endl;
    cout << "2: Do Something" << endl;
    cout << "3: Do Something" << endl;
    cout << "4: Do Something" << endl;
    cout << ":" << endl;
    cin >> choice;
    return choice;
}

int main()
{
    // declare an empty int
    int output;
    do
    {
        // assigning the int to
        // return value of menu()
        output = menu();
    } while(output > 0 && output < 5)

    // Do Something Else
}
```

**Note**

using `||` in a condition will return as soon as one of the statements are true or false. Where as `&&` will only return if all the statements are either true or false in the condition.

Or, are you looking for another form of answer?